# Use of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, shared-ptr

I have a vector of `std::shared_ptr`'s, and I also have a class member called `std::shared_ptr current_ptr`, and it's purpose is to refer to only one of the shared pointers in the vector at one time. It will never refer to a shared pointer that is not in my vector.

For this kind of "current pointer tracker" member, is it better to just use a raw pointer? Since `current_ptr` should be able to point to null, it can't be a reference to a shared pointer.

Comment: Use whatever makes your code easier to read. Any performance difference will likely be negligible.

Comment: You could use references and store an empty `std::shared_ptr` which would be returned, for instance, when vector would be empty

Comment: Why can't it be a reference to a shared pointer? Null references to objects (obtained by dereferencing a null pointer `Foo *p = NULL; Foo &r = p;`) are not allowed, but pointer references that happen to to refer to null pointers (`Foo **p = NULL; Foo *&r = p;`) are perfectly fine, as they don't dereference a null pointer.

Comment: @mewa so you're saying have an empty shared ptr member called `empty_ptr` and set `current_ptr` to be its reference if I want `current_ptr` when I want it to be null?

Comment: @Chara Yes, that's what I meant. But you could manage raw pointers as well, it's really only a matter of which approach seems more convenient to you :)

Comment: @Chara You can always use `shared_ptr<T>(NULL)` to create a shared_ptr equivalent of the null pointer to T.

Comment: @user4815162342 yup, thats what I meant in my comment above. I've decided to use a raw pointer though, thanks for your comments anyways

Comment: @user4815162342 `shared_ptr()` and `shared_ptr(NULL)` are semantically the same, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

Comment: I know you can use `.reset(T* p)` to change the pointer that a shared pointer stores, but is it true that `p` has to be unmanaged at the time of the function call?

Comment: @mewa Fair enough. I guess I didn't realize that by "empty shared_ptr" you meant just `shared_ptr()`. (For some reason I assumed you meant "pointer to an empty object that serves as sentinel.")

Comment: Don't use .reset(T* p) to point to some element in vector, just assign current_ptr=some_shared_pointer_in_vector. Use .reset() only when pointing to null.

Comment: @Chara Yes it is, because it calls `delete` before assigning a new value.

Comment: Using raw pointer means it will become invalid if the entry is removed from the vector.  Could you explain why you are hesitant to use `shared_ptr` (or `weak_ptr`)?

Comment: `shared_ptr` is suitable when shared ownership is encountered - if this is the case then no, you shouldn't use a raw pointer - if not, the I'd use a `unique_ptr`. Raw pointers are to be better avoided anyway.

Comment: @M.M I will be dereferencing the `current_ptr` often, so using `weak_ptr` would mean calling `lock()` a lot of times right? As for using `shared_ptr`, since `current_ptr` will be changing what it's pointing to often, I will have to call `.reset(T* p)` every time I want it to point to something else. Since `p` is always managed by a smart pointer in my vector, I will get undefined behaviour (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset).

Comment: @Chara `reset` is for taking ownership. Use assignment operator from another `shared_ptr` to share ownership.

Comment: @M.M ah i see, thanks